# Reuse a function with setState in several components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, this

I have a function within a react component which needs to be used in another file

```
class App extends Component{
    changeMessageState(message) {
    this.setState({
      message,
    });
  }
render(){
return(
  <div>hello</div>
);
}
```

now, I want to use `changeMessageState` in a different file, but I dont know how to export this.
so, how can this be done?
i was thinking of putting changeMessageState in a separate file and call it from both places i.e. within the react component and in the other file from there only.
the problem is that if I put this in a separate file, then what will 'this' refer to? it wont refer to the component anymore, right?
so, how do I accomplish this?

EDITED TO EXPLAIN MORE:
actually, I have a separate file where I am using firebase to login
and when there's an error in the login process, I want to set the error message in there and display it in the App component.
so, I wanted to use the changeMessageState from within App inside the firebase login function and thus error message can be set from there.
that's what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 4):

You can pass `this` as argument:

```js
function changeMessageState(component, message) {
  component.setState({
    message,
  });
}

// then in your components
changeMessageState(this, message)
```

Comment: Nice one @GG. ..!

Comment: okay, but the other place where I want to use this function, the 'this' should still refer to the original App's this, wherever I use it.
it shouldnt point to a different 'this'

Answer (score 1):

If you wan't to call a function of one component from within the other components that are not directly related to this component then you can declare the function as a static member of the class and use it elsewhere by importing this component like

```
export default class App extends Component{
    static changeMessageState(message) {
         // logic here
    }
    render(){
       return(
          <div>hello</div>
    );
}
```

and use it like

```
import App from 'path/to/App'
....
App.changeMessageState(value)
...
```

However `this` isn't really available inside a `static` method and you can't do setState within it.

If you wish to setState of the component which changeMessageState is being called from then I guess you can simply add it in a separate file like

```
export const changeMessageState = (message) => {
     this.setState({message});
}
```

and then to use it, import first like

```
import { changeMessageState } from 'path/to/changeMessageState'
```

and use it like

```
changeMessageState.call(this, message);
```

Or better you need a shared state for all the component, then you should really look into using `redux` which provides a way for components to keep a shared state.

One other solution is provide a callback from the function that you wish to call `changeMessageState` from, for instance

```
export const login = (callback) => {
    //your logic here
    req.then((res) => {
         callback(res)
    }).catch((error) => {
         callback(error)
    }) 
}
```

and use it in App component like

```
login((message) => {
     this.changeMessageState(message)
})
```

Comment: and I wont need to export the function separately?? if yes, then this is what I am looking for

Comment: No you won't need to export this function separately

Comment: great. let me try it out

Comment: I tried it out and i get this error - Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined
and even the vscode linter says -- changeMessageState should be placed before constructor

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, this isn't available inside a static method, can you explain more on what you want to acieve, maybe there is another method

Comment: Do you want `changeMessageState` to change the state of App component only from whereever it is called or setState for the own component

Comment: yes, that's what I want to achieve.
i want to use changeMessageState from within the firebase login process and show the error message in component.
explained a bit more in original question above.

Comment: Why don't you call the firebase login function from inside the App component, any reason

Comment: well, I need to keep things clean. and maintain separation of concerns. so firebase is in it's own file.

Comment: the client wants it like that actually

Comment: I guess, then you might need to make use of redux, or provide a callback/Promise from firebase login function, which you can then use in App to call `changeMessageState`

Comment: I didnt quite get the callback/Promise part. could you explain a bit more on this. this could be helpful

Comment: From you Firebase login function you could return a Promise or else the login function could take a callback which is called then action is complete something like

`login(callback) {
     // You actions here
    .then(res) {
         callback(res);
   } 

}
`
and use it like `login((res) => {
    this.changeMessageState(res);
})` in App

Comment: hmm, yeah. that makes sense.